# Uploadify file extension filter option not working?

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, filter, uploadify

I'm using the following uploadify option:

```
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
```

But I continue to get the option for uploading "All files". 
I'm expecting it to say "custom" or something but it still says all files (lower left hand dialog). I can still upload any file.

[image: Uploadify dialog]

Why isn't this working?

Comment: have you tried to upload a different file extension (ex: .zip) ? if so, what was the result ?

Comment: See http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/-- 
fileDesc is required when using fileExt, are you using that?

Comment: @Tuga Good idea, I tried that but it had the same result.

Comment: @james_schorr Damn I feel like an idiot haha. Thanks this worked! Can you post this as an answer:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/-- fileDesc is required when using fileExt, are you using that?

Answer (score 7):

For Uploadify v.3.1 they are called [`fileTypeExts`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypeexts/) and [`fileTypeDesc`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypedesc/).

Comment: Thanks for that answer, couldn't work out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For Uploadify v 3.2.1, they are called fileTypeExts and fileTypeDesc, but it does not work on chrome Versión 47.0.2526.106 m.
its work on firefox and IE.
regards